# passing variable to mongodb query in meteor app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I'm trying to get started with a simple meteor app to search a database.  I've got a single  input box from which I get the search query with the following code:

```
Template.search.events = {
'keydown input#search' : function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        var item = document.getElementById('search');
        Template.results.results(item.value)    
        //console.log(item);    
        item.value = '';
    }
}
}
```

I pass the search query to another function which is supposed to query the mongodb and print the result in the template:

```
Template.results.results = function (item) {
return Products.find({sku: item});
}
```

However, it never finds the item!  If I run the same query in Chrome's console it works.  If I replace {sku: item} in the code with (for example) {sku: "A2277"} (which is in my db) then it works!  If i create a new variable inside the Template.results.results function such as var item = "A2277" that works too.  What's going on here?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template helpers were designed to be called by your template, not directly by your event handlers. Your code just asks a query to happen and return a value, but it isn't tied to your template in any way. Instead, you should use a session variable like so:

```
Template.results.results = function() {
  return Products.find({sku: Session.get('itemSku')});
};
```

Then in your event handler you can do something like:

```
Template.search.events({
  'keydown input#search': function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      var $item = $('#search');
      Session.set('itemSku', $item.val());
      $item.val('');
    }
  }
});
```

Note I used jQuery here to set/get the item values. Anyway, that should set the session variable and reactively redraw the results.